# How can I create a new array with each epoch using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am creating a physics informed neural net (PINN) in TensorFlow. The vanilla PINN works fine, training as expected, but I want to create a novel addition. My addition, without going into too much detail, iterates through patches of my predictions to refine the prediction. I need a new array to store these refined predictions without overwriting the original prediction, but I am facing difficulties on how to define this array, such that the gradients of my model can be found using automatic differentiation (tf.GradientTape). I don't want to overwrite the original prediction until all of the patches have been processed, as I need to call elements of the original prediction to construct each patch. The shape of my new array of refined predictions will be the same shape as my prediction array.

I have tried a couple of approaches.
Initially, I tried to create a new tf.Variable with each iteration, but tensor flow doesn't allow this (ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables).
I then tried to create the tf.Variable globally, and wipe the entries with each epoch, but when I try to optimise my model, the loss doesn't reduce, I think because the AD is struggling to track the operations (gradient is None).
I've also tried to create a deep copy (using tf.identity) of my predictions, that can be overwritten, but again the operations aren't fully recorded on the gradient tape, and my model doesn't optimise.
I've been looking at trying tf.TensorArray but that doesn't support reassignment of elements (which I could work around, it would just be a pain), and I fear that as it is an EagerTensor the gradient will still be None.

I am using Tensor Flow v2 on a jupyter notebook.

EDIT added overview of code:
Apologies in advance for my layout, I am mostly self taught and there are sure to be faux pas contained in my code.

This first set of subroutines contains only the routine name, input and output, and a brief description of the purpose.

```
init_model(layers)=model
'''Initialise the trainable part of the feed forward neural network; weights, biases, activation function.'''
MSE(truths,preds)=MSE
'''Calculate the MSE of two input vectors, output one number'''
find_uv(psi, tape2, x,y)=u,v
'''find the velocity from the stream function (the two outputs of the nn)'''
find_dvtvs(p,u,v, tape2, x,y,t)=u_x,v_x,p_x, u_y,v_y,p_y, u_t,v_t, u_xx,v_xx, u_yy,v_yy
'''find the further derivatives for the residual of the governing equations'''
get_residual(p,u,v, u_x,v_x,p_x, u_y,v_y,p_y, u_t,v_t, u_xx,v_xx, u_yy,v_yy):
'''calculate the residuals from the Navier Stokes 2D equations'''
train_step() = loss, dataerror, physicserror
'''compute current loss for this epoch, and the gradient of the loss wrt the trainable paramenters'''
```

My training loop:

```
layers = [3,10,10,2] #input layer of xyt, two hidden layers of 10 neurons, output layer of psi (stream function) and p (pressure) 
N = 1000             #number of epochs
model = init_model(layers)
for i in range(N+1):
    loss, dataerror, physicserror = train_step()

@tf.function
def train_step():
    '''compute current loss for this epoch, and the gradient of the loss wrt the trainable paramenters'''
    loss, grad_theta, dataerror, physicserror = get_grad(model, dxy_coords, dxy_truths, hx_coords, hy_coords )
    # Perform gradient descent step
    optim.apply_gradients([
          (grad, var)
          for (grad, var) in zip(grad_theta, model.trainable_variables)
          if grad is not None
        ])
    return loss, dataerror, physicserror
```

The following subroutines have been reduced for readability and would generate a nonsense output.
In my file they are in reverse order, but I thought it would be easier to read if written this way, with the deepest nested function last.

```
def get_grad(model, dxy_coords, dxy_truths, hx_coords, hy_coords):
    '''Find the gradient of the loss function wrt the trainable elements'''
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(model.trainable_variables)
        loss, dataerror, physicserror  = compute_loss(model, dxy_coords, dxy_truths, hx_coords, hy_coords )
        g = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    del tape

    return loss, g , dataerror, physicserror
```

```
def compute_loss(model, dxy_coords, dxy_truths, hx_coords, hy_coords ): #train_coords, train_truths, train_phycol
    '''During training, find the loss, data error, physics error'''

    coords = tf.concat([dxy_coords, hx_coords, hy_coords],0)          #stack all my coords to be column x,y,t and rows dxy,hx,hy
    dxyshape = (20,5,5)
    hxshape =  (20,4,5)
    hyshape =  (20,5,4)

    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape2:
        x,y,t = coords[:, 0:1], coords[:, 1:2], coords[:, 2:3]
        tape2.watch(x)
        tape2.watch(y)
        tape2.watch(t)

        #feed forward neural network predictions
        psiandp = model(tf.stack([x[:,0], y[:,0], t[:,0]], axis=1))
        psi = psiandp[:,0:1]
        p = psiandp[:,1:2]
        u, v = find_uv(psi, tape2, x,y)
        puv = tf.stack([p[:,0], u[:,0], v[:,0]], axis=1)               #dim (500+400+400, 3)

        puv_proj = HCP(puv, dxyshape, hxshape, hyshape )               #dim (500, 3)

        #to find further derivatives, they MUST be wrt all coords
        #so stack the half predictions back in
        puv_half = puv[500:,:]                                        #dim (400+400, 3)
        puv_all = tf.concat([puv_proj, puv_half], 0)                  #dim (500+400+400, 3)

        #pull the p u and v predictions apart
        p_all, u_all, v_all = puv_all[:, 0:1], puv_all[:, 1:2], puv_all[:, 2:3]
        #find all derivatives required for the residuals
        u_x,v_x,p_x, u_y,v_y,p_y, u_t,v_t, u_xx,v_xx, u_yy,v_yy = find_dvtvs(p_all,u_all,v_all, tape2, x,y,t)

    del tape2
    p, u, v = p_all, u_all, v_all

    #reducing the loss calculation to just be on the dxy coords: (and lumping ALL predictions together)
    dxy_preds = tf.concat([p,u,v, u_x,v_x,p_x, u_y,v_y,p_y, u_t,v_t, u_xx,v_xx, u_yy,v_yy], axis=1)[:500, :]
    
    #now pulling all the components out of the big prediction array (dxy_preds)
    p,u,v =       dxy_preds[:,0:1],   dxy_preds[:,1:2],   dxy_preds[:,2:3]
    u_x,v_x,p_x = dxy_preds[:,3:4],   dxy_preds[:,4:5],   dxy_preds[:,5:6]
    u_y,v_y,p_y = dxy_preds[:,6:7],   dxy_preds[:,7:8],   dxy_preds[:,8:9]
    u_t,v_t =     dxy_preds[:,9:10],  dxy_preds[:,10:11]
    u_xx,v_xx =   dxy_preds[:,11:12], dxy_preds[:,12:13]
    u_yy,v_yy =   dxy_preds[:,13:14], dxy_preds[:,14:15]

    MSEu = MSE(dxy_truths[:,0:1],u)
    MSEv = MSE(dxy_truths[:,1:2],v)
    dataerror = MSEu + MSEv

    f_u, f_v = get_residual( p,u,v, u_x,v_x,p_x, u_y,v_y,p_y, u_t,v_t, u_xx,v_xx, u_yy,v_yy )
    myzeros = tf.zeros(f_u.shape, DTYPE)
    physicserror = MSE(f_u,myzeros) + MSE(f_v,myzeros)

    #physics informed loss
    loss = 0.5*dataerror + 0.5*physicserror

    return loss, dataerror, physicserror
```

```
def HCP(puv, dxyshape, hxshape, hyshape ):
  '''turns predictions to constraint patches then processes the patch to get one value then outputs the processed values'''

  #first pull out the quantity of each of the types of data
  Ndxy = dxyshape[0]*dxyshape[1]*dxyshape[2]                         #=500
  Nhx  = hxshape[0]*hxshape[1]*hxshape[2]                            #=400
  Nhy  = hyshape[0]*hyshape[1]*hyshape[2]                            #=400

  #then we pull out p,u,v from the three types of data, and reshape so they are in 3d array
  p_dxy = tf.reshape(puv[:Ndxy,0:1],           dxyshape)
  u_dxy = tf.reshape(puv[:Ndxy,1:2],           dxyshape)
  v_dxy = tf.reshape(puv[:Ndxy,2:3],           dxyshape)
  p_hx  = tf.reshape(puv[Ndxy:(Ndxy+Nhx),0:1], hxshape)
  u_hx  = tf.reshape(puv[Ndxy:(Ndxy+Nhx),1:2], hxshape)
  v_hx  = tf.reshape(puv[Ndxy:(Ndxy+Nhx),2:3], hxshape)
  p_hy  = tf.reshape(puv[(Ndxy+Nhx):,0:1],     hyshape)
  u_hy  = tf.reshape(puv[(Ndxy+Nhx):,1:2],     hyshape)
  v_hy  = tf.reshape(puv[(Ndxy+Nhx):,2:3],     hyshape)

  #then we want to find out how many patches there are (no patches on the boundaries)
  t_patch = dxyshape[0] - 1                                          #=19
  x_patch = dxyshape[1] - 2                                          #=3
  y_patch = dxyshape[2] - 2                                          #=3
  N_patch = t_patch*x_patch*y_patch

  #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  #THIS IS THE SECTION I AM HAVING DIFFICULTY WITH
  #I want deep copies of p_dxy, u_dxy, v_dxy, something I can overwrite and also something that tracks the operations for later automatic differentiation (AD)
  p_proj = tf.identity(p_dxy)                           #the identity function doesn't track the operations, so no AD
  u_proj = tf.TensorArray(u_dxy)                        #this is quite lazy, I would actually need to create a tf.TensorArray dimension by dimension then 'assign' each term, but when I do this the operations are not recorded again like with the identity
  v_proj = tf.Variable(v_dxy)                           #again I am being lazy, I would create an empty Variable array of the same dim as v_dxy, then 'assign' each term. This works for one epoch, then tensor flow tells me that it can't create new Variables with the same name with each epoch (error in og question)
  #these will be overwritten, all but the boundary values, and each *_proj has the same dimensions as their corresponding *_dxy
  #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  #then we need to loop across all patches, processing and storing each one
  for ts in range(t_patch):
    for xs in range(x_patch):
      for ys in range(y_patch):
        #I don't want to include what happens in this loop
        #The output is a processed p,u,v value for the center of each patch
        p_, u_, v_ = process(the_patch)

        #store the predictions from this patch- leaving boundary values intact
        #depending on the array type I will need different methods of overwriting, this is the one needed for tf.Variable
        p_proj[ts+1,xs+1,ys+1].assign(p_)
        u_proj[ts+1,xs+1,ys+1].assign(u_)
        v_proj[ts+1,xs+1,ys+1].assign(v_)
        

  #my matrices are full with projected values, in xyt 3dim storage. 
  #I need to reshape them all (unpeel)
  p_proj = tf.reshape(p_proj, [Ndxy])
  u_proj = tf.reshape(u_proj, [Ndxy])
  v_proj = tf.reshape(v_proj, [Ndxy])

  #finally group the predictions together
  puv_output = tf.stack([p_proj, u_proj, v_proj], axis=1)

  return puv_output
```

Comment: Can you add your code? Or a template as close to your actual code?

Comment: Do you need code that you can run? Even just code for a basic PINN will be quite lengthy, is it ok to just give an overview of what the other routines do and toy code for the particular subroutine I'm struggling with?

Comment: If the model is a classical fully-connected neural network, I think that the training loop, the operations to compute loss to be minimized and the code related to your 'special feature' may be enough. In order to have a broader picture.

Comment: I have added a overview of the code in an edit to the original question. Let me know if you need any further elaboration.

Comment: This is a hotfix. Did you try to define a second variable `puv2 = tf.stack([p[:,0], u[:,0], v[:,0]], axis=1)` and feed it to the `HCP` function? (or even use `puv = puv2 = tf.stack(...)`). I thought that the `tf.identiy` would have worked...